# deciveOrientationControls seems to be distorting the camera when defining xyz for the camera

Tags: three.js

I'm still new to Three.js but I've been loving it's capabilities so far. One thing I've been working on is a 360 that depending on whether or not you've on a desktop/mobile device it'll load different controls. The problem I'm seeing is the DeviceOrientationControls.js is moving the camera hugely out of place when I try to define an XYZ.

Here's a link: http://www.freeptools.com/mapster/testing-360s2.php

If I ignore the XYZ and just set the Z position of the camera to 1, then the device orientation controls works perfectly as expected.

The script is here: http://www.freeptools.com/mapster/js/360widget-dev2.js. The camera positions are being defined around line 392. I'm not sure what's causing this, but it doesn't seem to be device specific.

**EDIT**: I'm including some photos to demonstrate this

- OrbitControls: http://freeptools.com/mapster/uploads/normal.png
- DeviceOrientationControls:
  http://freeptools.com/mapster/uploads/distorted.png

Comment: Can you create a 50-line demo to demonstrate the issue? What does "distorting the camera mean"?

Comment: I added a screen shots of the camera where ti looks normal and one where it appears distorted. I didn't include a code sample because I'm not really sure why it's happening. I know it happens with the DeviceOrientationControls when I define the XYZ positions of the camera. I'm currently at a loss for the cause though.

Comment: Are you keeping the camera in the center of the environment sphere?

Comment: no, I allow it to move. But I don't understand why with the same camera position, one control looks normal, and the other looks so off.

Comment: Move the environment sphere as the camera is moved.